# Series representation of $1/x^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to WolframAlpha the series representation of $1/x^2$ is

$$\frac{1}{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-1)^{n} (-1)^n (n+1) $$

Can somebody tell me how to prove this result?

Comment: This is not _the_ series representation. It is the series representation about the point $x=1$, which is valid for $|x-1|<1$. For any non-zero $a\in\Bbb R$, there is a series representation for $1/x^2$ about the point $x=a$, valid for $|x-a|<a$; and this representation is different for every $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the ordinary Taylor series for $f(x) = 1/x^2$ around the point $x=1$. So you find the coefficients by finding the derivatives there.

Alternatively, you can start from the geometric series
$$
\frac{1}{1-u} = 1 + u + u^2 + \cdots,
$$
differentiate term by term with respect to $u$ and substitute $u =1-x$.

Answer (score 4):

This is valid for $|x-1|<1$. Setting $y=1-x$, it's equivalent to
$$\frac1{(1-y)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)y^n$$
which is valid for $|y|<1$. Take the geometric series
$$\frac1{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n$$
and either differentiate it or square it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: start from the geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac1{1-x}.$$
Alternatively: Taylor at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

By the geometric series, you obtain

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}; \vert r\vert < 1$$

You can also consider the Taylor Series, which gets

$$f(x) = a^{-2}-2a^{-3}(x-a)+\frac{6a^{-4}}{2!}(x-a)^2-…$$

and see what happens at $a = 1$...